# How to put a horizontal line (separator) between rows in Gtk::TreeView

Tags: gtkmm, separator, gtktreeview

I'm writing a program using `gtkmm-2.4` GUI package in Linux. How can I put horizontal lines as separators between rows of a TreeView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [set_grid_lines](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeView.html#a9f6601372b4b0d271669efac7c16ecf9):

```
someTreeView.set_grid_lines(Gtk::TREE_VIEW_GRID_LINES_HORIZONTAL);
```

The actual appearance of the lines is controlled by the current Gtk Theme.